# How to break line with divs'

Tags: html, css

Good morning. I've problem. Assume we've 100 divs. I want display ones in horizontal line but when line's ended create new line. I tried with only display: flex but when there's many divs, div's width is narrowing

```
<div class="refs-row">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
  <div class="reflink-square">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.refs-row{
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

}
.reflink-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="refs-row">
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
</div>
```

Try This

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to the parent div `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` to make the child div wrap, dont forget to close all your divs

```css
    .refs-row{
    background-color:red;
    width:100vw;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    overflow:none;
    }

    .reflink-square{
    background-color:blue;
    width:10%;
    margin:2px;

    }
```

```html
    <div class="refs-row">
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
      <div class="reflink-square">A</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-wrap: wrap`  to wrap the divs, and you have to close all the divs `</div>`

```css
.refs-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.reflink-square {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="refs-row">
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
  <div class="reflink-square"></div>
</div>
```